# How to get rid of black hair algae?

Tags: aquarium, water-parameters, cleaning, maintenance, algae

My aquarium is infested; it's on the plant leaves/pebbles/glass.

I tried to remove everything manually but it soon bloomed again, big water changes, shortening the lighting time, but no success.

It used to have some guppies; now, only snails (*Melanoides*/*Physidae*) and a single *Ancistrus* in 60 liters.

And for plants, only a few *Cryptocoryne wendtii*.

Comment: It would be useful to know how big your tank is and what lives in it beside the algae :)